# Excel file crashes on opening, while opens fine on another computer

Tags: excel, windows

I have a `xlsm` file that I saved a couple of hours earlier. I try to open it now, but to no avail. I sent the file to another computer and tried opening it on it and it opens ok. I then tried to send the file back to the current computer and open again, but it still crashes.

I tried deleting `Excel` folder in `AppData` folder, but it didn't seem to work.

What might be causing this issue and what can be done about it?

I have Windows 7 OS and Microsoft Excel 2013.

Comment: Can you open other spreadsheets on the computer where Excel is crashing? Did you try deleting a certain sheet from the workbook to see if it could open it then? I don't currently know what the problem is, but I would try several tests like this to hopefully narrow down what is causing the crash.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Other excel files open fine. How can I delete a worksheet if I can't open the workbook?

Comment: You said you can open it on another computer right? Delete a sheet from the workbook on that computer, send it back, and see if you can open it on the computer in question.